# How to make a released console app run on Window Console Host in any case?

Tags: c, windows, console-application, windows-terminal

I have programmed a game running on console. The console host I chose to use is Window Console Host because I can easily and successfully setup and confiugre it with the API functions from `<Windows.h>`. The game's window I expected was like below:
[image]

I had made the window of above console app not able to be resized by anyway. But when I released that app and sent to my friend to test, then it became like this because he was using Windows Terminal:

[image]

Is there any solution to make the released console app run with fixed console host on any computer to keep my setup?

Here is the code snippet I wanted to setup the console's window:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
int main(void) {
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    
    //set font size
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi = { sizeof(cfi) };
    // Populate cfi with the screen buffer's current font info
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hStdout, FALSE, &cfi);

    // Modify the font size in cfi
    //cfi.dwFontSize.X *= 2;
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 36;

    // Use cfi to set the screen buffer's new font
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hStdout, FALSE, &cfi);

    //delete cursor
    const CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO CUR_INFO = { 10, 0 };
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hStdout, &CUR_INFO);

    //set size of console
    SMALL_RECT WindowSize = { 0, 0, CONSOLE_WIDTH, CONSOLE_HEIGHT};
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdout, 1, &WindowSize);

    //remove console screen buffer. This command must be put after 'SetConsoleWindowInfo',...
    //...and value of 'NewSize' must be greater than CONSOLE_WIDTH and CONSOLE_HEIGHT just 1
    COORD NewSize = { CONSOLE_WIDTH + 1, CONSOLE_HEIGHT + 1 };
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hStdout, NewSize);

    //disable resize console by mouse
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SIZEBOX);

    //disable maximizing
    DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(hWnd, FALSE), SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

    //Hide scroll bar
    ShowScrollBar(hWnd, SB_BOTH, FALSE);

    //disable select text by mouse
    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE);

    //set title of console window
    SetConsoleTitleW(TEXT("Console Run"));
}
```

Comment: According to MSDN, `SetConsoleWindowInfo` _fails if the specified window rectangle extends beyond the boundaries of the console screen buffer._ So maybe try calling `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` before `SetConsoleWindowInfo`.

Comment: Side note: checking and logging the return values from all those Windows API calls would probably help you diagnose the issue. [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is [microsoft/terminal#5094](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094). The Windows Terminal currently doesn't support a commandline application resizing the dimensions of the viewport.

You could try making a helper exe or `.bat`/`.cmd` file that runs

```
conhost.exe -- yourGame.exe
```

and that will manually launch `yourGame.exe` in the Windows Console Host, regardless of their Default Terminal setting.